# How to securely add authenticated user UID into firestore document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

We can securely query documents using authenticated user's UID, using firestore rules like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /stories/{storyid} {
      // Only the authenticated user who authored the document can read or write
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't find how to fill the data with the authenticated user UID.

The below document is working fine, but it was sent from the client-side, and I don't think it's secure, as the request could have tampered with another user UID.

```
{
  title: "A Great Story",
  content: "Once upon a time...",
  author: user.uid,
  published: false
}
```

Basically, I need a user UID value from Firebase server, just like we can insert a timestamp from server with `firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't think it's secure, as the request could have tampered with
> another user UID.

By adding the `request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.author` clause in your `write` security rule you will guarantee that the request cannot be tampered with another user uid.

This clause verifies that the value of the field `author` corresponds to the uid of the user executing the write.

---

More explanations in the doc, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#properties) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#auth_tokens) as well as [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) on how the integrity of ID tokens is verified.

---

**Important:** Note that we use `request.resource.data.author` instead of `resource.data.author`, because, as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation):

> The `resource` variable refers to the requested document, and
> `resource.data` is a map of all of the fields and values stored in the
> document.

and

> the `request.resource` variable contains the **future** state of the
> document.

As a consequence you should most probably separate the `read` and `write` rules.